# Facebook Graph API: is the endpoint https://graph.facebook.com/<page_id>/events working?

Tags: facebook, events

My application has been reviewed and approved with the pages_read_engagement permission. I have no trouble accessing post of the pages that have granted the app that permission. However, I am also interested in accessing events published and/or hosted by these pages.

I've noticed that the endpoint [https://graph.facebook.com/v7.0/<page_id>/events](https://graph.facebook.com/%3Cpage_id%3E/events) is working. However, it is not returning events for some pages, even though I passes the page's access_token as parameter. Instead, it is working for some other pages.

I looked at the documentation for more clarification but apparently this endpoint is not documented. It looks like it is not even mentioned in the documentation. Am I missing something? Is it still supported? And why it doesn't return events for some pages?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/event/ says, _“Access to Events on Users and Pages is only available to Facebook Marketing Partners.”_

Comment: I agree with you but that doesn't explain why I can still access events using the API for some pages. Also, that link doesn't refer exactly to the endpoint I am using. Do you have any further information?